# OutOfMemoryError in Snapshots.commitAndClose

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have created a Android app that can be downloaden from the Google Play Store. I'm getting reports back with the following stacktrace:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:56)
com.google.android.gms.common.data.BitmapTeleporter.writeToParcel(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.zzb.zza(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.games.snapshot.SnapshotMetadataChangeCreator.zza(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.games.snapshot.SnapshotMetadataChangeEntity.writeToParcel(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.games.internal.IGamesService$Stub$Proxy.zza(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.games.internal.GamesClientImpl.zza(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.games.internal.api.SnapshotsImpl$3.zza(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.games.internal.api.SnapshotsImpl$3.zza(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.common.api.zza$zza.zzb(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzd.zza(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzd.zzb(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzg.zzb(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.games.internal.api.SnapshotsImpl.commitAndClose(Unknown Source)
com.peerkesoftware.blockcrusher.data.savegame.SaveGameManager.save(SaveGameManager.java:176)
com.peerkesoftware.blockcrusher.data.savegame.SaveGame.save(SaveGame.java:25)
com.peerkesoftware.blockcrusher.fragments.GameFragment.sendScoreToServer(GameFragment.java:309)
com.peerkesoftware.blockcrusher.fragments.GameFragment.onGameOver(GameFragment.java:260)
com.peerkesoftware.blockcrusher.controls.GameBoard2$1.run(GameBoard2.java:220)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

As far as I have seen it's only happening on a Samsung Galaxy Note3(T-Mobile) SM-N900T device. But that device should have plenty of memory available. Anybody knows why I get this error? And how to prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

The out of memory exception is for your app, not the device. What does depend on the device is how much memory your app is allowed to use. Samsung has probably set a lower limit than others for that specific device. keep in mind that the hire resolution a device has the more ram is needed by your bitmaps.

You can see how much ram your app can use like this:

```
final int maxRamKiB = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024;
```

To see how much you have free like this:

```
final int freeRamKiB = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() / 1024;
```

Prior to saving your game you can check how much free ram you have, if it's too little, you can free some prior to starting the save operation. Likely candidates for ram hogs are bitmaps.

This is a good start for investigating more precisely how your app uses its ram:
https://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html

Comment: While I can check the amount of memory in use by my app, I don't see how my app can be the problem. It's a very simple game that is not using much memory. There are barely any bitmaps in there that consume memory.

Comment: If you are getting an out of memory exception then I'm afraid that it is your app that is the problem. Perhaps you're leaking memory if you don't keep a lot of bitmaps etc in ram. You will never get an out of memory exception in your app from something another app or the system is doing. since your app is the foreground app you have first pick of system resources, should the device run low on ram the system will kill off other apps to give your app ram.

Comment: To get you an idea of how much ram your app is allowed to use you can call getMemoryClass. Some devices have as low limits as 16-48mb per app. Some have more.

Comment: I never had an out of memory exception until I started using the Save Game feature from the Play Game Services. Can it be that there is something wrong there?

Comment: From the stack trace its clear that the play game service either has or is in the process of creating a bitmap. My guess is that it takes a screenshot and sends it along with the save game data. Your only options are to free some ram prior to calling save game or to stop using the service. I would also strongly advice you to check your code for memory leaks.

Comment: Your comment got me thinking. I indeed send a bitmap with my savegame. On the device mentioned (Samsung Note 3) there is of course a high resolution. This would create a huge bitmap. That could be the problem. I'm going to change some code to reduce the bitmap size.

Comment: Sounds to me that it's very likely that you have your answer there, :)

Comment: If this solved your question remember to accept the answer and up vote :)

Answer (score 0):

You can ask for a larger memory size by putting

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

in your Android manifest.

Before using this method consider the following quote:

> However, the ability to request a large heap is intended only for a small set of apps that can justify the need to consume more RAM (such as a large photo editing app). Never request a large heap simply because you've run out of memory and you need a quick fix—you should use it only when you know exactly where all your memory is being allocated and why it must be retained. Yet, even when you're confident your app can justify the large heap, you should avoid requesting it to whatever extent possible. Using the extra memory will increasingly be to the detriment of the overall user experience because garbage collection will take longer and system performance may be slower when task switching or performing other common operations.

From:
https://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/articles/memory.html

Comment: While this is true, it's usually a good idea to avoid it, if possible. It should not be your first solution.

Comment: This setting is not intended for my app.